# Unknown field(s) () specified for

Tags: django, python-3.x

What is wrong here?

> error: File "/Users/user/Desktop/Dp1/project6/project6/urls.py", line
>   18, in 
>       from myapp6 import views   File "/Users/user/Desktop/Dp1/project6/myapp6/views.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from myapp6.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm   File "/Users/user/Desktop/Dp1/project6/myapp6/forms.py", line 15, in
>   
>       class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):   File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/Djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py",
>   line 266, in **new**
>       raise FieldError(message) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (profile_pic) specified for UserProfileInfo

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete='models.PROTECT')

    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)

    portfolio_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp6.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password',)

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```

Comment: I think you miss spell your field name, the field name is `portfolio_pic` not `profile_pic `

Answer (score 0):

You have field portfolio_pic in your UserProfileInfo model, but in UserProfileInfoForm you have profile_pic form field which should be portfolio_pic.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','portfolio_pic')
```

For that:

```
class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```